# How to get hyper-v host detail description using power shell command?

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

How to get list of hosts and details(viz. Capacity,CPU count,Memory) in MS Hyper V using power shell commands?

Comment: Take a look at Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/?view=win10-ps).

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should start with taking the [Tour], continue to read [ask] and maybe [mcve] before you proceed. Did you try to search for it? I'm pretty sure that you're not the first human being with this requirement.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you launch PowerShell as an administrator you can use the `Get-VM` command to get some pretty good info easily.

```
PS>Get-VMHost | 
         Select ComputerName,FullyQualifiedDomainName, MaximumStorageMigrations,`
          LogicalProcessorCount, @{N='Memory(GB)';e={$_.MemoryCapacity / 1gb -as [int]}} 

ComputerName FullyQualifiedDomainName MaximumStorageMigrations LogicalProcessorCount Memory(GB)
------------ ------------------------ ------------------------ --------------------- ----------
ELOPE        WORKGROUP                                       2                    16         64
```

If we like this view, we can export it as a CSV file and use this for auditing by just piping into `Export-CSV` like so:

```
Get-VMHost | Select ComputerName,FullyQualifiedDomainName, MaximumStorageMigrations, LogicalProcessorCount, @{N='Memory(GB)';e={$_.MemoryCapacity / 1gb -as [int]}} | 
    export-csv c:\temp\vmhost.csv
```

[image]

But that's not all we can do...

If you wanted to make a real report out of this, you could instead use `ConvertTo-HTML` with a little bit CSS for the basis of a real nice report.

```
$OSVer = Get-ciminstance win32_operatingsystem | select caption,Version
$pre=@"
<body id="css-zen-garden">
<div class="page-wrapper">
<style>
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: 'Corben', Georgia, Times, serif;
}
p, div, td {
    font-family: 'Nobile', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1 { 
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
}
h2 {box-shadow: 0 0 1em 1em #ccc;}
<br>

</style>
    <h1>Hyper-V Report</h1>
    <h2>$($env:ComputerName) - $($OSVer.Caption) [$($OSVer.Version)]</h2>
        </header>

        <div class="summary" id="zen-summary" role="article">
            <p>A demonstration of what can be accomplished through a little bit of PowerShell and CSS</p>           
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

"@


Get-VMHost | Select ComputerName,FullyQualifiedDomainName, MaximumStorageMigrations, LogicalProcessorCount, @{N='Memory(GB)';e={$_.MemoryCapacity / 1gb -as [int]}} | 
        ConvertTo-html -CssUri http://www.csszengarden.com/examples/style.css  -PreContent $pre -PostContent "<i>Created automatically on $($Env:ComputerName) at $(get-date)" |
            Out-file c:\temp\F.html -Force

start C:\temp\f.html
```

[image]

Comment: The question was about _host_, so `Get-VMHost` should be used.

Comment: I have tried `Get-VMHost` but it does not contain detailed description of the host .Do you know how we can get more details out of this command? Like it's capacity,total number of CPUs and Memory.

Comment: @SumitSawant PowerShell cmdlets show the first four or five properties of a cmdlet.  To see all of them, you can use the pipe character like this with `Get-VMHost | Format-List`, this will show you all of the properties.  If it doesn't work, ensure you have Hyper-V perms for your account.